# reader.readLine()) Returning null But printing Content

Tags: android, web, web-scraping

I want to get server response (actually is text from a website) even though it is returning `null` but is printing the content.
CODE:

```
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        String response = "Test";
        Log.i("String Content", response);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        while ((response = reader.readLine()) != null){
            Log.i("String Content", response);
            Log.i("Server Response", reader.readLine());
        }
        Log.i("String Content", response);
```

OUTPUT:

```
04-10 17:55:05.128    3404-3425/com.example.example I/String Content﹕ Test
04-10 17:55:05.129    3404-3425/com.chatter.chatter I/String Content﹕ [ 04-10 17:55:05.129  3404: 3425 I/Server Response ] Successfull!
04-10 17:55:05.129    3404-3425/com.example.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-279
    Process: com.example.example, PID: 3404
    java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
            at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
```

How is it possible? Can someone help me out with this?.

Comment: Each call to `reader.readLine()` jumps to the next line. So when you call it twice in your while-loop it will jump two lines.

Comment: so how can i fix this? I am sorry but i am just starting with android apps and java

Comment: Also try to explain your question better and maybe give us a clearer example. Don't use `System.out.println()` for that but rather use Android's `Log.v()`, `Log.d()`, `Log.i()`, `Log.w()` and `Log.e()` methods for better (and more understandable) logs.

Comment: I want to return the response in String format but it is returning null

Comment: How does your `InputStream` look like? Your log ouput isn't very clear.

Comment: I have modified my code, check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `InputStream` and want to save its contents to a `String` you should go this way:

```
try{
    inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream , StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    String str = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(str);
    }
    String response = sb.build();
    Log.d("String Content", response);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It says: `sb.build();` cannot resolve this method ` , i have imported this: `import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;`

Comment: this worked but tell me if there are some disadvantages and why do you put 8192 in StringBuilder:
try{ inputStream = connection.getInputStream(); 
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)); 
       String str = null; 
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8192); 
       while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
              sb.append(str); 
        } 
       response = sb.toString(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }